# django url regex doesn't match

Tags: regex, django, django-urls

Not sure why this doesn't match any urls in urls.py. I checked with a regex checker and it should be correct.

urls.py:

```
url(r'^toggle_fave/\?post_id=(?P<post_id>\d+)$', 'core.views.toggle_fave', name="toggle_fave"),
```

sample url:

`http://localhost:8000/toggle_fave/?post_id=7`

Checked using [this](http://www.nvcc.edu/home/drodgers/ceu/resources/test_regexp.asp) simple regex checked. Seems right. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the urlconf isn't used to match the request.GET parameters of your url. You do that within the view.

you either want your urls to look like this:

```
 http://localhost:8000/toggle_fave/7/
```

and match it using:

```
url(r'^toggle_fave/(?P<post_id>\d+)/$', 'core.views.toggle_fave', name="toggle_fave"),
```

with your view that looks like:

```
def toggle_fave(request, post_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id)
    ...
```

or

```
http://localhost:8000/toggle_fave/?post_id=7
```

and your urls.py:

```
url(r'^toggle_fave/$', 'core.views.toggle_fave', name="toggle_fave"),
```

and views.py:

```
def toggle_fave(request):
    post_id = request.GET.get('post_id', '')
    if post_id:
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id)
    ...
```

Comment: OK I understand, thank you. Though I think the regex part in urls.py is misleading then.